# $X\times X\simeq X$ implies $X$ is contractible?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I've seen claimed in several papers that, given a space $X$, if $map(S^0,X)$ is homotopy equivalent to $map(*,X)$, then $X$ is contractible. I don't know why this is so.

It is clear to me that $map(S^0,X)\simeq X\times X$ and $map(*,X)\simeq X$ and the homotopy equivalence $X\times X\simeq X$ induced by $map(S^0,X)\simeq map(*,X)$ is simply a projection -say, onto the first factor. So the questions boils down to prove that $X\times X\simeq X$ (given by the projection) implies $X\simeq *$. I'm not sure how to prove this fact.

My idea is to replace $X$ by $X\times *$ and consider the homotopy equivalence $X\times X\simeq X\times *$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto (x,*)$. From this I'd like to prove that its components are homotopy equivalences.

I've seen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1385693/if-the-product-of-two-homotopy-equivalences-is-a-homotopy-equivalence-are-the-fa) asking precisely if the components of a homotopy equivalence are homotopy equivalence but it doesn't have an accepted answer (and the existent answer doesn't satisfy me because since we don't know exactly what is $G$, I don't see how the equalities of compositions follow).

Comment: If $X$ is a product of infinitely many copies of $S^1$, say, then $X \times X$ is homeomorphic to $X$, but $X$ is not contractible.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri But the projection of $X\times X$ to $X$ is not a homotopy equivalence?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri good point, but I'm interested in the case when the projection is the homotopy equivalence. I've edited the question so that this becomes clear.

Comment: Could you edit the title, too, at least to add the missing $X$?

Comment: The equalities of the compositions in the question you link don't depend on what $G$ is.  They just come from $\iota_Bf=F\iota_A$ and $fp=qF$ which are both obvious from the definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only true assuming $X$ is nonempty.  Suppose $X$ is nonempty and the first projection $p:X\times X\to X$ is a homotopy equivalence, with homotopy inverse $f:X\to X\times X$.  Fix a point $a\in X$ and let $i:X\to X\times X$ be the map $i(x)=(x,a)$.  Since $pi=1_X$, $f=fpi\simeq 1_{X\times X}i=i$, so in fact $i$ is a homotopy inverse to $p$.

Let $H:X\times X\times I\to X\times X$ be a homotopy from the identity to $ip$, so $H(x,y,0)=(x,y)$ and $H(x,y,1)=(x,a)$.  Now simply observe that if we define $h:X\times I\to X$ by $h(x,t)=q(H(x,x,t))$ where $q:X\times X\to X$ is the second projection, then $q$ is a homotopy from the identity map on $X$ to the constant map with value $a$.  Thus $X$ is contractible.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking that the inclusion should be the homotopy inverse but I couldn't show it before.

Comment: More generally, if a morphism has both a right inverse and a left inverse, then they are equal.  So since $i$ is a right inverse to $p$, it must be equal to any left inverse of $p$ in the homotopy category.

Comment: Dear @EricWofsey , Does this result still hold when $X\vee X\simeq X$?

Comment: @M.Ramana: Yes, and the proof is essentially the same (just "dualized").

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks very much. I got it.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give it a try, although I'm not topologist.

The projection $pr_1: X \times X \rightarrow X$ is a homotopy equivalence, which means that there is a map $(f, g): X\rightarrow X\times X$, sending $x$ to $(f(x), g(x))$, such that the compositions with $pr_1$ are homotopy equivalent to identity maps.

So we have $\Phi = (f, g)\circ pr_1$ which sends $(x, y)$ to $(f(x), g(x))$, and we know that it's homotopy equivalent to $\operatorname{Id}_{X\times X}$.

This means that there is a continuous map $h:X\times X\times [0, 1]\rightarrow X\times X$, such that $h(x, y, 0) = (x, y)$ and $h(x, y, 1) = (f(x), g(x))$.

Now pick any point $x\in X$ and define a map $u:X\times[0, 1]\rightarrow X$ such that $u(y, t) = pr_2\circ h(x, y, t)$. We have then $u(y, 0) = y$ and $u(y, 1) = g(x)$.

Therefore the identity map on $X$ is homotopy equivalent to the constant map sending any point to $g(x)$, and we are done.